# `bundle install` returning error even for gems already installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm new to Rails. I installed Rails fine but if I add an extra gem to the Gemfile (any gem at all that's not already in there) and run `bundle install`, I get this error:

```
$ bundle install
/home/mcrittenden/Dropbox/Code/omgwtf/Gemfile:40:in ``': No such file or directory - rmagick (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/mcrittenden/Dropbox/Code/omgwtf/Gemfile:40:in `evaluate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:138:in `definition'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

This happens even if the gem it's complaining about is already installed. In this case, the gem is correctly installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Note: I know I should be using RVM, and I am, but for the purposes of this post I didn't include it so that it could be ruled out as a possible culprit.

Comment: have you tried the usual troubleshooting means like `gem update --system`? and which version of rails is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please show us your gemfile.  That is an important piece of information.  My theory is that you wrote `require 'rmagick'` but it should be `gem 'rmagick'`.

My other theory is that you used back ticks instead of quotes.  Please copy and paste your gemfile so we can see exactly what you wrote.

Comment: It's almost certainly the backticks.  Changed one of my gemfiles to use a gem with backticks and got the identical error.

Comment: It was the back ticks. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, the three different kinds of quotes have different meanings in ruby and you should be careful about choosing which one to use.  Given that all the other gems in your Gemfile didn't use backticks, you should be wary of using backticks when you add a new gem.  The backticks cause ruby to execute the string as a shell command.